Cannot change the entry Data Extension in copied journey: Failed to find the Automation selected for this Journey
I have copied a journey that has a data extension entry source (from an automation).
I have built a new data extension and automation and I want to connect it to the new copied journey.
I can change the data extension as the entry source, but when I want to change the schedule to the new automation SFMC gives this error message:

Failed to find the Automation selected for this Journey

Is there any way to fix this journey than recreating it from scratch?

You shouldn't click "Edit" button to change the schedule but there is a drop down right there let you "Change Schedule Type" where you can select the new automation schedule.

